# Python: User input as a list index

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to use user input as an index for a list, but I keep getting the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple." Here is what I have:

```
def sort(j, k):
    sublist = list[j, k]
    print sublist
    sorted = sublist.sort
    print sorted

operation = raw_input() 
sort(operation[5], operation[7])
```

The user is supposed to input

```
SORT 3 5
```

and a subset of the original list will be sorted.

Comment: First `sorted = sublist.sort` this is incorrect. It should be `sublist.sort() return sublist`.

Comment: "I am trying to use user input as an index for a list" For **what** list? The code here has multiple issues and does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your (immediate) problem is at this line:

```
sublist = list[j, k]
```

Presumably `list` is a list of items<sup>1</sup>.  When you do `somelist[a, b]`, python sees something equivalent to `somelist[(a, b)]`.  So, you can see, you're indexing `somelist` with a `tuple` (which doesn't work).  Chances are that you want a `slice`.  In that case, you'll do:

```
sublist = list[j:k]
```

Even after making this change however, you'll still have problems -- Notably, `j` and `k` in your code are of type `str` and lists want to be indexed/sliced with integers (or `None`...)<sup>2</sup>.  So, now we have:

```
sublist = list[int(j):int(k)]
```

At this point, you might stop seeing errors, but you won't see the results you want which brings us to the next problem.

```
sorted = sublist.sort
```

Here you're just assigning a bound method to a name.  You're not actually sorting anything.  If you want to sort the sublist (in place), you'd do:

```
sublist.sort()
print(sublist)
```

If you are ok with sorting it out of place, you can use the builtin `sorted` function (provided you haven't named something else `sorted` ;-)

```
print(sorted(sublist))
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note, it is generally accepted that naming a variable the same thing as a builtin type can lead to hard to read and debug code :-).</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>While we're at it, I might mention there is a better way to chunk up your string -- You can `.split` it.  e.g.  `operation.split()` will give you `['SORT', '5', '7']` rather than needing to make assumptions about the input and indexing the input string.</sup>

Comment: Missed a few other things :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Yeah, I was trying to tackle the problems one at a time (in sequential order) so OP would see the various mistakes as they popped up...

Comment: @IgorHatarist -- Thank you.  When you've spent as much time on StackOverflow as I have, you begin to learn a few markdown tricks (and which html tags StackOverflow's markdown renderer doesn't sanitize ...)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

1. Your function is called `sort`, which is the name of a built-in method.
2. You are not calling the method in this line `sorted = sublist.sort` (its missing ()).
3. You are giving each letter from the input as an argument to your function.
4. This: `list[j,k]` is what is causing your problem, because `j,k` is a tuple.
5. `sort` is in an in-place operation, so it will return `None`, which is what you will end up printing.

To fix these issues:

```
def my_sorter(j, k): # Changed method name
    sublist = my_list[int(j):int(k)] # You need j:k
    sublist.sort() # Note, no return value, because its in-place
    print sublist

user_input = raw_input('Please enter the indices: ')
j,k = user_input.split()
my_sorter(j,k)
```

Comment: With regards to (1), while `sort` is certainly the name of a built-in method... it's not exactly problematic in the same way it would be if it were shadowing the name of a _built-in function_.

Comment: Note, you still have the problem of `j`, `k` being strings :-)